# Hibernate many to many Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have no idea what is the problem and how to solve this. I have `Articles` and `Images` which are mapped many to many.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Article")
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int articleId;
    private String createDate;
    private int state;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="articles")
    private Set<Image> images = new HashSet<Image>();

//setters and getters
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Image")
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int imageId;
    private String imagePath;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ArticleImage", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "articleId") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "imageId") })
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<Article>();

//setters and getters
}
```

These are my 2 tables mapped. I also have a table in database: `ArticleImage` with `articleId` and `imageId`.

In my controller when I create my `article` object and `image` object I can save them without problem but if I try to set the `image` in `article` I get an error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into ArticleImage (articleId, imageId) values (?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`appdatabase`.`articleimage`, CONSTRAINT `fk_ArticleImage_Article1` FOREIGN KEY (`articleId`) REFERENCES `article` (`articleId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`appdatabase`.`articleimage`, CONSTRAINT `fk_ArticleImage_Article1` FOREIGN KEY (`articleId`) REFERENCES `article` (`articleId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I tried to set everything and save to the database but I get the error. I also tried to save the `article` and `image` to the data base(without setting the article in image and it's working). Then set the `article` in the `image` and then update the `image` but I get the error.

How should I handle this ?

EDIT:

```
Article article = new Article();
article.setCreateDate(dateFormat.format(date));  
article.setState(1);
articleService.create(article);

Image img = new Image();
img.setImagePath(path);
imageService.create(img);

Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<Article>();
articles.add(article);
img.setArticles(articles);
imageService.update(img);
```

I also tried to set everything and then create them.

My Dao are like this:

```
public void create(Article article) {
    session().save(article);
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on both ends, but I don't think that's your current problem, so I won't call this an answer.

Comment: Can you show the code of your current attempt at making the connection?

Comment: IMHO you should remove the Set initialization from both classes. Let Hibernate do that.

Comment: @DonRoby I have this in spring mvc and the rest of the app is working fine, so the connection to the database it's working..

Comment: @j3ny4 ok, I will do that but I don't think it will solve my problem..

Comment: I meant your attempt at connecting articles and images.

Comment: @DonRoby I edited the post and wrote the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was not in code. It was in my database. I had some entries in `Article` and in `Image` and I think that was why I got the error. All I did was to create my database from workbench again with no entries in my tables and now it's working :).